# Overrided CreateParams Doesn't Take Effect

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I overrided a form(System.Windows.Forms.Form and I will call it Form0)'s *CreateParams* property like this

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams _CreateParams = base.CreateParams;
        _CreateParams.ExStyle |= (WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
        _CreateParams.Parent = IntPtr.Zero;
        return _CreateParams;
    }
}
```

This window should not be able to be activated(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE) and have no icon shown in the taskbar(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW).

It works WELL when I use

```
Application.Run(new Form0());
```

But it doesn't work as what I expected when I use

```
Form0.Show()
```

I want to know why and how to make it take effect while using `Show()`.

Comment: See [the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20859048/1997232).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Application.Run() and Form.ShowDialog()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314514/whats-the-difference-between-application-run-and-form-showdialog)

Comment: Not sure how either of those questions answer this one. The question is, *where* are you calling `Form0.Show()`? Are you trying to do it in your `main` method? If so, then no, that won't work.

Comment: @CodyGray I have another form(I will call it Form1) to put on foreground,and there's an Textbox in Form1,I call Form0.Show() when that Textbox got focus.

Comment: And what happens after you call `Form0.Show()` in the `OnFocus()`?

Comment: @andlabs It shows an icon in the taskbar and can be activated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style of your window. You don't need to add the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`. `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` takes care of it by default:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams _CreateParams = base.CreateParams;
        _CreateParams.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        _CreateParams.ExStyle &= (~WS_EX_APPWINDOW); //<----
        _CreateParams.Parent = IntPtr.Zero;
        return _CreateParams;
    }
}
```