# I can't close this form

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

why I can't close this from it gave me an error message (Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form4' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on)

my form code;

```
 System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();

private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { myFunction2();}
private void myFunction2()
    {
        t.Interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
        t.Start();
        t.AutoReset = false;

    }
 private void T_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        myFunction();

        t.Stop();
        t.Enabled = false;
        this.Close();
    }
private void myFunction()
    {


        var form6 = new Form6();
        //form6.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        form6.ShowDialog();}
```

**Edit** 
I get help from a friend to change this in my code but still, the from4 open and form6 open much time.

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

private void myFunction2()
    {
         t.Interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        t.Tick += T_Elapsed;
        t.Start(); 
    }
 private void T_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myFunction();
        this.Invoke((new Action(() => 
                       this.Close();
        }))); 
    }
 private void myFunction()
    {
        Form6 form6 = new Form6();
        form6.ShowDialog();}
```

Comment: Which timer type is `t`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman sorry I update it now

Comment: The Elapsed calls on a **thread pool**  thread, while `myFunction()` is trying to do operations on the **UI thread** . You can use [Dispatcher.Invoke() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @styx The member `Dispatcher` is WPF-only - winforms has similar methods, like in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Winforms has an "owning-thread" model.

What does that mean?

This model prevents you from accessing an UI component from another thread, not the one which created it.

Why?

Because GUI components are not thread-safe. and should not be, since they'll be much slower. So, WinForms throws an exception like that at you when you try to access a GUI component from another thread - not the **owned thread**.

But why does this happen toyou?

Because `System.Timers.Timer` executes its callback in its own thread, which isn't the thread that created the GUI (the main thread of the app). So, you can't access from its callback to any GUI component.

What's the solution?

You **can** access an GUI component from another thread by a tool called a **Dispatcher**. But if all you want is a simple timer, you have nicer solution.

Simply use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`. This timer is specific to WinForms, and handles all the black work with the dispatcher for you. (Note: WPF has `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` for the same purpose).

But, there's one pitfall: this timer has not `AutoReset` property. So, you should remove the event by hand after one run, like:

```
private void T_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myFunction();

    t.Stop();
    this.Close();
}
```

Since you're closing the window, this is not really needed, but for safety...

Also, note that you don't need both `Stop()` and `Enabled = false` together, they are identical (I personally prefer `Stop()`, I think it's more readable).

In your example (with `AutoReset`) you didn't need `Stop()` at all - `AutoReset = false` run the callback only one time.

#### Edit:

Although it isn't needed in your case, I append an explanation about "how to use the dispatcher".

Each WinForms' form has a *Dispatcher*, and some methods related to it. The most important are `Invoke()` and `BeginInvoke()` (two overloaded versions, I'm talking about the first which takes `System.Delegate`).

These methods enable you two access GUI components from not-owning thread, only from the method passed as parameter (in most cases, you must cast it to `System.Delegate` first).

The difference is, that `Invoke()` returns only after the method called, while `BeginInvoke()` is asynchronous; it returns immediately.

So, you can rewrite you code as follows:

```
private System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
    t.Interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    t.AutoReset = false;
    t.Start();
}

private void T_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((Action)(() => // You can use `BeginInvoke()` as well
    {
        this.Close();
    }));
    // Or
    // this.Invoke(new Action(() => // You can use `BeginInvoke()` as well
    // {
    //     this.Close();
    // }));
}
```

**Note:** Never put long-running tasks inside `Invoke()` or `BeginInvoke()`! since they're executed in the owning thread - not in the called thread, they'll freeze the GUI - it's much easier to not use threads at all... Put the calculations in the thread, and call these methods only to update the GUI!

#### Edit 2:

After I saw what you did with my answer, I was shocked... It seems you even didn't read it! You chose both the solutions: the winforms timer (the good), and the dispatcher (the bas, in this case)! simplify you `Tick` event so:

```
private void T_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myFunction();
    Close();
}
```

Also, in your `myFunction()`, you show your second form **in modal form**. That say, that the method won't return after the second form is closed. See [What's the difference between Show(), ShowDialog() and Application.Run() functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859048/whats-the-difference-between-show-showdialog-and-application-run-functio) for more details. I think you want to show your second form modeless.

Comment: how can I use the Dispatcher her

Comment: I try to use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`  bout it not working with me

Comment: @ahmed_eltot93 What's the error with `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

Comment: `this.Invoke((Delegate)(() =>{this.Close();}));` i have a red line here why ??

Comment: Put the calculations in the thread, and call these methods only to update the GUI! how is that ?

Comment: @ahmed_eltot93 What do you mean?! If you have some threads (and you know how to use threads correctly) - that's because you have two do heavy calculations. That I've said, calculate the heavy things in other thread for not freezing the GUI, then just update the GUI with the results by the dispatcher.

Comment: bro, I'm a beginner in coding I swear I don't know what should I do I just what to close this form :S

Comment: what should I do in `private void T_Elapsed`

Comment: @ahmed_eltot93 With `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` it worked me excellent. With `System.Timers.Timer` - my problem. The line wasn't valid. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: I can't use this code with the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` i get a red line in `t.Elapsed` and `t.AutoReset`

Comment: `t.AutoReset` - I told you this property didn't exist in `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, just remove it like in the answer!! And about `t.Elapsed` - it's called now `t.Tick`.

Comment: still the first form not closing

Comment: no it like good bout the second form open many time and the first from still open

Comment: Please display us your code after the changes. Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
private void T_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            myFunction();
            t.Enabled = false;
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
 private void myFunction2()
    {
        t.Interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        t.Tick += T_Elapsed;
        t.Start();

    }
    private void myFunction()
    {
        t.Enabled = false;
        t.Stop();
        this.Hide();
        Form6 form6 = new Form6();
        form6.ShowDialog();}
```